# Syntax error on token util, delete this token

Tags: java

Вот, собственно, решил обучиться языку Java. Для этого начал изучать "Философию Java" Б.Эккеля, но запоролся на первой же программе.

```
import java util.*;
public class HelloDate {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello. Today is ");
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }   
}
```

Пытаюсь скомпилировать в эклипсе, но он выдает ошибку в первой строке. Как я понимаю, это связано с библиотеками JRE. Собственно, не могли бы вы подсказать, в чем проблема и как ее решить?

[image]

Comment: Надеюсь Эккеляв Вы в оригинале читаете (недавно решил наконец взглянуть на перевод, думал в последнем издании что-то улучшилось)

Хотя тут в коде все нормально, остается скорее всего смотреть что там с проектом

upd еще бы посмотреть какая у вас ошибка (эклипс должен показывать)

Comment: Нет, читаю как раз-таки переведённую версию, 4 издание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас просто пропущена точка в первой строке.

```
import java.util.*;
           ^
           |
```

Успехов в изучении Java!